# How to reverse a numpy array using loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reverse

Given this numpy array:

```
 Input:  nums = np.array([0] * SIZE, dtype=int)
 Output: [ 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100]
```

I need to reverse the array elements using a loop (not using a numpy command directly).
So the desired outcome would be: [100, 90 ,80,....10]
How can you reverse these using a for or while loop structure?

Here is what I've got so far.

```
for i in range(len(arr)-1, -1, -1):
        print(arr[i])
```

This will print the reverse order, but how can store these elements back into the array in this reverse order?

> I am aware that numpy has built in functions to do this, however I want to understand this from a first principals approach.

Comment: nums[::-1] just uses python slicing

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, google is your friend as it looks like numpy has a built-in for this exact purpose.

Comment: "How do I solve this homework problem" is not a Stack Overflow issue.  Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: ""Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: _and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._ That part is missing, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100], dtype=int)
rev = np.zeros(nums.size, dtype=int)
for i in range(nums.size):
    rev[nums.size - (i + 1)] = nums[i]
```

`np.zeros(s, dtype=d)` creates an array of size `s` filled with zeros of type `d`.

In this case `rev` is the reversed array and `nums.size` is the same as `len(nums)`

Comment: `nums.size is the same as len(nums)` Be careful, that's only true for 1-dimensional ndarrays.

Comment: The = a[i] is giving an error of the name a is not defined. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @AMC I know, that's why I wrote "In this case"

Comment: @PascalvonFellenberg I just wanted to make sure, I was worried it might be ambiguous :)

Comment: @JasonMcKinnerney sorry, my bad it shoud be `rev[nums.size - (i + 1)] = nums[i]`

Comment: Thats it! Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100], dtype=int)
rev = np.zeros(nums.size, dtype=int)
for i in range(nums.size):
    rev[nums.size - (i + 1)] = nums[i]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so that you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Comment: Doing an np.array reverse in a for loop will take about 5 orders of magnitude more time than using a numpy builtin.